# Keeping backend validation in sync with frontend validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, validation

A lot of frameworks like Laravel do not provide any suggestions on how to do frontend validation. This is understandable coming from a backend framework.

But it would be really nice to provide javascript validation beforehand so that users can immediately see if something is wrong when they are filling out a form.

I know how to do validation on the backend with something like Laravel and I know how to do it on the frontend with javascript. The problem that arises though is that a lot of frameworks do not cross this frontend/backend boundary yet I need to keep them the validation in sync with eachother.

I can't have validation errors on the frontend that no longer apply to the backend validation. How do people deal with this?

Do people normally just do backend validation and pass a flashbag or errors to the user and simply skip the frontend validation? I feel that trying to keep the validation for frontend and backend the same could be error-prone and quite some work.

**Edit**

Although there is already an answer for the question I would love some more input on it. What people are using, custom solutions or thoughts on how to efficiently tackle this problem are all welcome.

Comment: I suppose you could write code in your PHP that generates javascript to apply the same server side rules to the client side.

Comment: while this is an interesting question, I think it would fit better to programmers.stackexchange.com. I guess you'd get more answers there, too. Please link to the question, if you decide to open one. If you don't, I might some day.

Comment: wait, there already is one: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/298537/justifying-programmatically-ensuring-frontend-and-backend-validations-are-synchr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sync it by yourself. Pass laravel validation rules to a view and deal with them. There are some examples like this.

As for me, I usually meet full backend validation with simple front-end one. Something like min and max length only. Front can't check if a value is unique.

https://dotdev.co/form-validation-using-vue-js-2-35abd6b18c5d#.q0r9nkibc

There is another approach but it slightly increase load of a server. First send a form with a flag `validate=true`, which only validates a form. And second request do as always, i.e. validation+action. It requires a simple js-library to handle it, not a huge refactoring.

Comment: This works fine when you are working a small application but with a huge application with dozens of forms where things change a lot I really don't see this is a viable option. If I were to change something either front or backend I would constantly have to remember to keep their counterpart updated as well otherwise I would slowly get inconsistent logic all over the place. Even if we are simply talking about require checks, etc. This would seem like a headache with fragmented logic over time.

Comment: As for js-validation: *If I were to change something either front or backend I would constantly have to remember to keep their counterpart updated* Why? You have rules like ["name" => "required|max:10"] just in one place and pass it to a view.

Comment: If you are passing these rules to javascript from PHP you are already creating a system for it that is currently not yet in place. I want these rules to apply to Javascript validation as well. There is no need to send a form and waste resources if the validation can be checked with Javascript before even sending the data.

Comment: Well, it is a good idea to have it out of the box. But we have to build it by ourselves since it doesn't exists...